# Store the result of var_dump in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, var-dump

I have a form contains many text box,checkbox,radio etc.

for the posting page i used var_dump to capture result.

I need to store the result of var_dump in mysql .
Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly possible, just not generally wise to do so. var_dump() is generally used as a tool for debugging, not as a data storage format; [var_export()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) will give you the same format, but returning it as a string that can be stored rather than simply displaying it to screen.

Your problem will be trying to do something with the data subsequently, because it's a format that's not easily reversible: you'll have problems trying to parse it back to the original form variables.

You might instead want to consider using [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) or [serialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) instead, both of which are reversible formats, making it easy to restore the original data in a form that a script can then work with again.

Comment: i used var_export($_POST).How to store the result of this in a mysql table

Comment: `How to store the result of this in a mysql table` Do you know how to write data to a MySQL database at all? Look at functions in the php docs like the [MySQLi functions](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), and read some of the examples there, paying particular attention to prepared statements and bind variables

Comment: The result is like this array ( 'color' => 'red', 'm_status' => 'yes', 'c_status' => 'yes', 'b_status' => 'yes', 'hobies' => array ( 0 => 'games', 1 => 'reading', 2 => 'writing', 3 => 'internet', ), )

Comment: I need to store this as exactly same in a table column

Comment: Have you looked at the link I posted to working with MySQLi? HAve you written any code to try and store the data? Have you created a database to store the data in?